# Is there a way of making cm work in Reportlab? I've tried importing the units but they're returning inaccuracte dims

Tags: python, dimensions, reportlab

So this code draws the rectangle, and it comes out at 2cm, however, it is supposed to be 7cm high but is coming out at 6.7cm Is there anyway to make it spot on accurate. I've tried Reportlab website, youtube and forums but nothing has worked so far.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

c = canvas.Canvas(FILENAME_AND_LOCATION, pagesize=A4)
c.translate(cm,cm)
c.rect(1.75*cm,3.85*cm,1.5*cm,7*cm)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: onscreen with the pdf view set to 100% am I doing something ridiculously wrong. Like I said the 2cm dim seems to be pretty accurate

Comment: I've just printed it out too. The 2cm width is not out by much maybe a mm or less. but the 7cm dims are coming out at 6.7cm. Not a great problem for this project but it will be when I'm printing out more technical measurements in my next one. I was just wondering if there is a way of clearing it up.

Comment: I've also now tried Adobe Acrobat and Microsoft edge to load the pdf. Both I put on 100% both coming back inaccurate.